# Mandrill template: how to test templates with testing handlebars?

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I am using Mandrills I want to test emails with tesing handlbars so that emails look good , not with missing handlebar values

Any help??

Comment: Any new information on this? I'm also stuck on how to test the templates using handlebars. The render(..) method still doesn't support setting merge_language: 'handlebars'      :(

Comment: Sorry no update on it yet, For testing, I always trigger email with handlebars which comes from DB in my application, I didn't find any way on mandrill itself to test template with testing handlebars

Comment: sadly, it seems you can only template parameter passing by generating a test email using curl. SendGrid has a better template editor which allows you to define some test data and preview the results. It's too bad this feature is missing from Mandrill